# mysite.co.uk/wordpress redirects to mysite.co.uk?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have seen many similar posts about similar problems, but they all seem to say delete the redirect plugin but the only plugin I have is google analytics. 
The site was working ok, but suddenly redirects to the main site
if you enter or click a link to http://www.mysite.co.uk/wordpress it redirects to http://www.mysite.co.uk
i can find no way to change this even with the .htaccess file
any ideas?

Comment: Things don't just suddenly stop working. Something happened. You need to work out what. Server change or update? Server crash? Software install or update-- theme, plugin, WordPress itself, PHP, something? Check your logs. Ask your host. Post [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) And... 1) post all of the relevant code here and not as a comment to an answer. 2) Use ___real___ URLs. Fake ones are utterly useless.

Answer (score 0):

Check your general settings page, if the correct URL is filled in there.

Check if your Cpanel has no site redirect enabled.

And do post your htaccess here please.

Comment: general settings are set to http://mysite.co.uk/wordpress on both lines

Comment: .htaccess has this part for wordpress # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Is that htaccess located in your domain mysite.co.uk or in the folder wordpress?

Comment: the wordpress section of the .htaccess is the same in both the main folder and the wordpress folder

Comment: Do you have a Admin Panel on that domain? Is there a redirect set in that panel?

Comment: do you mean within cpanel?

Comment: yes, chech your Cpanel if there isn't a 302 site redirect filled in there.

Comment: i have redirects only because all my pages were shtml and i had to change them to php, but this was before i had wordpress on there, and wordpress worked until last week, no redirects setup have anything to do with wordpress

Comment: I think, if you have redirects there linking to your old domain, then you found your problem though

Comment: they aren't linking to my old domain, they redirect from mysite.co.uk/(x)-file.shtml to mysite.co.uk/(x)-file.php because the .shtml files were indexed on the internet

Comment: If your site worked before, are those redirects the only thing you changed?

Comment: the redirects have always been there since march, i only added wordpress around august, until last week wordpress worked fine

Comment: What changed then?

Comment: i made a new entry on wordpress blog, seems to be the only thing, not sure why this made any difference though, hence why i am here

Comment: Try testing with [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) if you can make a difference

Comment: well i added a redirect using it from /wordpress to goto /wordpress/index.php but it makes no difference

Comment: Can u give ur site url please?